# Android move data between activities

Tags: android

Example
I have 4 activities.
A B C D

A is a list of objects.

B C D are used to add a new object.

So A calls B then C then D .

However C or D have button to 'add the object'

When going up from B or C or D  to activity A , A  should have a List with these objects.
Even if user tap back items should be 'saved'

However I dont want to start a new Intent at C or D because i dont want user to go back to A and then click again add new item.

I have been adviced to keep these data at application object. Is there any other suggestion ?

Comment: what's wrong with application object?

Comment: Why don't you add Home button on action bar for activity b c d? All pointing toactivity A

Comment: Can you save the information in a database and retrieve it in onResume in Activity A?

Comment: @DroidT yes database seems a solution.But seems an overkill to create a whole database to just pass some items!!!

Comment: You could create a Singleton class if you want to save it in memory and class A could access the information from there.  Another option could be have a callback system between the Activity a and all of the other classes if they are fragments.

Comment: What did you try so far? What are the Object you want to pass?